# comma separated item in list comprehension python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have following code:

```
 read_files = glob.glob("*.log")

 with open("result.txt", "wb") as outfile:
    for f in read_files:
      with open(f, "rb") as infile:
         outfile.write(infile.read())       

 with open("result.txt", encoding="utf8") as f:
    b = f.readlines()   

 c=[re.findall('\d+ \d+ \d+ \d+ \d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}',i) for i in b]
 c=[i  for i in c if i!=[]]
```

Now if i try to do the following ,

```
 [i[0].split(' ')[0],i[0].split(' ')[1],i[0].split(' ')[4] for i in c]
```

I am getting bellow error:

```
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can anybody help

Comment: `[(i[0].split(' ')[0],i[0].split(' ')[1],i[0].split(' ')[4]) for i in c]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add parentheses in order to create a list of tuples:

```
[(i[0].split(' ')[0],i[0].split(' ')[1],i[0].split(' ')[4]) for i in c]
```

But you are still unnecessarily doing the same splitting operation multiple times for each `i`. For better performance and readability, you could do:

```
[(x[0], x[1], x[4]) for x in (i[0].split(' ') for i in c)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to surround the argument with parentheses:

```
 [ (i[0].split(' ')[0],i[0].split(' ')[1],i[0].split(' ')[4]) for i in c]
```

so it makes a list of tuples.

Can you provide more detail? Like a print out of the variable `c`?